# How to make address field width wider on WooCommerce's Edit Order page?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Would be helpful since addresses are usually long and having the field a bit wider would make it easier to edit the text. Please advise.

Address field as shown in image below:

[image: Screenshot of Billing Address form fields]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to the `functions.php` file:

```
add_action('admin_head', 'custom_admin_stylez');

function custom_admin_stylez() {
  echo '<style>
    ._billing_address_1_field {
      width: 100% !important;
    }
    ._billing_address_2_field {
      width: 100% !important;
    } 
  </style>';
}
```